# How to handle cases where allocated object is never used

Tags: java, eclipse

In some cases, the constructor call is everything needed, and I do not need any method invocation on the created object. Depending on Java-Compiler-Preferences, Eclipse gives a warning/error "The allocated object is never used" if I do not assign the created object to a variable, or a warning/error "The value of the local variable is not used" if I assign it to a variable.

I know that I can turn off the warnings/errors in the Eclipse Preferences. My question is: For which reason does Eclipse report "The allocated object is never used"? And if there are good reasons, how should I handle these cases, where no method invocation on the created object is needed?

Comment: Note that it's a compiler warning, Eclipse is not generating this by itself.

Answer (score 5):

If all your class's logic is executed in the constructor, perhaps you should move it to a static method instead of creating an instance you'll never use.

A constructor is meant to create an instance of a class to be used later. I think you might be misusing the constructor.

EDIT (March 2024):

As of Java 22 (also available in Java 21 as a preview feature), you can avoid the warnings by using an unnamed variable:

```
DateTime _ = new DateTime(shell, SWT.CALENDAR);
```

or

```
var _ = new DateTime(shell, SWT.CALENDAR);
```

You can read about it [here](https://openjdk.org/jeps/456).

Comment: For example let us assume, I want to write a program that just displays a SWT DateTime Control. I just need the constructor call 
 
 new DateTime(shell, SWT.CALENDAR);

Only because my program does not do anything more, does it mean that I am misusing the constructor of DateTime? Or is the software design of the SWT DateTime Class bad? 
I can move the construction of DateTime to an own static method. But what is the gain of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

From Eclipse specs [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm),

> When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning when it encounters an allocated object which is not used, e.g.

```
if (name == null)
    new IllegalArgumentException();
```

But it reports as a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=236385). Just ignore it no need.